# How can I check the authorization in Cancancan in Ruby on Rails each time the user calls that action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, authorization, cancancan

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5 and I want that depending of the role of a User, the user can post 5 Posts or 10 or 15, and that is just a part of the several possible situations that I have to check for Authorization (for things that are not Posts for instance I have other situations that are a bit more complex), so I started using Cancancan (v 1.15.0) few days ago to don't make the User model too huge, so this way I have one class for each Role and in ability.rb I just merge the classes depending on the Role.

The problem is that using Cancancan apparently it checkes the Authorization only once. For example in Creating a Post, In Post#create the first line of code is:

```
authorize! :create, Post
```

In the Role class of the user, I have this code:

```
  if user.posts.size < 10
    Rails.logger.debug "If-size: #{user.posts.size}"
    can :create, Post
  else
    Rails.logger.debug "Else-size: #{user.posts.size}"
    cannot :create, Post
  end
```

I have some tests with RSpec and I see the first time the current_user (the one with that specific role) creates a Post using the controller (I mean, not by FactoryGirl or any other way that is not using the controller), it appears in log/test.log:

```
If-size: 0
```

But neither the Else nor the If appears ever again in the log, it doesn't matter how many Posts I create by the Controller, it only evaluates this condition the first time and the User get authorized to creates as many Posts as he wants because the first time the condition in the If is true and it is not evaluated each time the method create of the controller Post is called.

**EDIT**: Solved by the method suggested by MarsAtomic. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi Marta and welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer has helped you, look for the checkmark to its left and click on it to show others what helped you. Remember that in the future, people may run into the same problem and can benefit by reading your question instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CanCanCan isn't meant to dynamically evaluate roles based on conditions within your application. That type of functionality is best handled by your application's own logic, rather than an authorization tool.

You should consider adding a column to your `roles` table that indicates how many posts a particular role is allowed. This column would allow you to check on the number of posts each user (via role) is allowed to create.

Then, in your `posts_controller.rb`, you can wrap your post creation logic in a block that runs only if the user has not exceeded the maximum number of posts allowed:

```
def create
  if user.posts.size < user.role.max_posts
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    # flash an error on the page or redirect to an error page
  end
end
```